# how Proof by contradiction works with (r ∧ ¬r)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

"Proofs by Contradiction
Suppose we want to prove that a statement p is true. Furthermore, suppose that we can find
a contradiction q such that ¬p → q is true. **Because q is false, but ¬p → q is true, we can
conclude that ¬p is false, which means that p is true. How can we find a contradiction q that
might help us prove that p is true in this way?**
Because the statement r ∧ ¬r is a contradiction whenever r is a proposition, we can prove
that p is true if we can show that ¬p → (r ∧ ¬r) is true for some proposition r. Proofs of this
type are called proofs by contradiction. Because a proof by contradiction does not prove a result
directly, it is another type of indirect proof. We provide three examples of proof by contradiction.
The first is an example of an application of the pigeonhole principle, a combinatorial technique
that we will cover in depth in Section 6.2.
EXAMPLE 9 Show that at least four of any 22 days must fall on the same day of the week.
Solution: Let p be the proposition “At least four of 22 chosen days fall on the same day of the
week.” Suppose that ¬p is true. This means that at most three of the 22 days fall on the same
day of the week. Because there are seven days of the week, this implies that at most 21 days
could have been chosen, as for each of the days of the week, at most three of the chosen days
could fall on that day. This contradicts the premise that we have 22 days under consideration.
That is, if r is the statement that 22 days are chosen, then we have shown that ¬p → (r ∧ ¬r).
Consequently, we know that p is true. We have proved that at least four of 22 chosen days fall
on the same day of the week"(My discrete math book)

What I understand is that we assume the original propositional statement is false and we find a contradiction that results from that meaning ¬p → (r ∧ ¬r) this means p = True(T) the logic behind proof by contradiction is that ¬p → (r ∧ ¬r) = ¬(T) → (r ∧ ¬r) = F → (r ∧ ¬r) = F → F = TRUE because this Implication results in True our truth value of P = T is Correct. **So I am wondering if this explanation is true**, because that is what I understand from reading the book definition as it says **¬p is false** which means ¬p = F this means ¬(T) = F meaning p is true. I think my understanding is wrong somewhere as if this is how it works then ¬p → (r ∧ ¬r) = F → T also is a true implication so either way p is always true.

Comment: See [Proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction): yes. If the proposition to be proved is P, we assume P to be false, i.e., we assume ¬P and we derive a contradiction (example: two mutually contradictory assertions, Q and ¬Q). Since assuming P to be false leads to a contradiction, it is concluded that P is true.